# Problems with Heap Corruption - C

Tags: c, malloc

I am making a "simple" print out string, append string and remove section from a string. The append and new string works sometimes, sometimes it outputs nothing.
When i do:

```
char * temp = malloc(newSize);
```

It just stops outputting anything.

I have commented everything out in sections, trying to find the problem. Can't seem to find the problem, but google keeps coming up with "Heap Corruption".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char * data;
    int length;
} String;

int str_getLength(const char * characters)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (characters[index] == '\0') break;
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}

String str_new(const char * characters) 
{
    String result;
    result.length = str_getLength(characters);
    result.data = malloc(result.length);
    memcpy(result.data, characters, result.length);
    return result;
}

void str_append(String * str, const char * characters) 
{
    int charsLength = str_getLength(characters);
    str->data = realloc(str->data, charsLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < charsLength; i++) {
        str->data[i + str->length] = characters[i];
    }
    str->length = str->length + charsLength;
}

void str_remove(String * str, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
{
    if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex > str->length || endIndex < startIndex) {
        return;
    }
    int chunkSize = endIndex - startIndex;
    int newSize = str->length - chunkSize;

    char * temp = malloc(newSize);
    // for (int i = 0; i < str->length; i++) 
    // {
    //  if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
    //      temp[i] = str->data[i];
    //  } 
    // }

    // free(str->data);
    // str->length = newSize;
    // str->data = temp;
}
}

int main() 
{
    String str = str_new("Hello, ");
    printf("%s\n", str.data);

    str_append(&str, "this is my first C application.");
    printf("%s\n", str.data);

    str_remove(&str, 0, 3);
    printf("%s\n", str.data);

    free(str.data);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected it to output a modified string, it doesn't and sometimes it outputs nothing.
I am a beginner, sorry if it's a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the blaze answer.
There are few more problems.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < str->length; i++) 
// {
//  if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
//      temp[i] = str->data[i];
//  } 
// }
```

You will access out of bound for `temp`.
You need to maintain separate index for `temp`.

```
char * temp = malloc(newSize+1);
int k=0;
for (int i = 0; i < str->length; i++) 
 {
  if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
      temp[k++] = str->data[i];
  } 
}
 temp[k] = '\0'; 
 free(str->data);
 str->length = newSize;
 str->data = temp;
```

And

You are not `null` terminating the string after append.

```
str->data = realloc(str->data, str->length + charsLength +1); //current length + new length + \0
for (int i = 0; i < charsLength; i++) {
    str->data[i + str->length] = characters[i];
}
 str->data[i + str->length] = '\0'; //null terminate the new string
str->length = str->length + charsLength;
```

Comment: I think i have fixed my code, with a couple of your recommendations. Here is a link too the new work - https://repl.it/repls/RosyAggressiveFact

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your reallocation. First of all, you're not assigning the result of the `realloc` to `str->data`, so if the memory was reallocated to a different place, `tr->data` points to invalid memory afterwards. Second, you're not adding the sizes of the string and the appended part, you're just taking the size of the part that you're appending.

This here

```
realloc(str->data, charsLength);
```

Should be:

```
str->data = realloc(str->data, charsLength + str->length + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the first issue, thats fixed. But the second thing you mentioned, breaks the application further, I thought that too.

Comment: If I follow your second suggestion, this is the output - https://gyazo.com/b9fd7cd6853742d931e62c52e4c4e01d

Comment: @user5377005: If you want `str.data` to behave like a regular C string, you must append the null character, `'\0'`. You must also reserve space for it.